# C# - List of network devices

Tags: c#, wpf, local-network

I should show all the laptops in the local network.
I tried this one:

```
public static int GetAllIP(string[] args = null)
{
    string strHostName = new string("");
    if (args.Length == 0) {
        strHostName = DNS.GetHostName();
        Console.WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);
    } else {
        strHostName = args[0];
    }
    IPHostEntry ipEntry = DNS.GetHostByName(strHostName);
    IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < addr.Length) {
        Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr(i).ToString());
        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref i), i - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried this [one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using), don't work too. I mean, alway I get an empty array.

Any other idea how to do it?

Comment: that looks like you're looking up your *own* IP address, no? can I ask: *why* are you trying to get the IP addresses for all the laptops in the local network? that seems a very ... odd thing to do. Not to mention that a lot of the devices will be 'phones, printers, network actives, etc... not laptops. Most networks *actively don't want you* doing scans like this...

Comment: @Marc Gravell I have a local network with a couple of laptops. I need to show a list of laptops, select one and save the file to a selected laptop in a shared folder.

Comment: then whatever you're doing: either do it *from the laptop you want*, or know the host-name of the target laptop in advance